# How to Use Ajax in form alter in Drupal 7?

Tags: forms, ajax

I have created a content type named "main menu". I have few select lists which depend on one another. I wanted to display a different list when different checkboxes are selected. I figured out that I need to use Ajax to edit the form in order to achieve that but can anyone tell me how to use Ajax with hook_form_alter?

The form id of the form I am supposed to edit is "main_menu_node_form". When I try to access this form using `hook_form_alter()`, and add the `#ajax` property of the form fields, it seems that I am not able to do that since the fields are already rendered before the handle is passed to `hook_form_alter()`. Can anyone please help me solve this?

Note : I have created the content type using `hook_install()`.

```
function main_menu_content_type_form_main_menu_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  dpm($form);
  dpm($form_state);

  $form['field_mlnk'] = array(
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'main_menu_content_type_form_main_menu_node_form_alter_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'link-div',
      'method' => 'replace',
      'effect' => 'fade',
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: It would  be helpful to see the code of the form you are trying to alter, and the code you are using to alter it.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I have created a content type main_menu using hook_install function. I wanted to display fields while adding content according to the selection made in lists. Should I add the ajax properties in hook_install or in Hook_form_alter.

Comment: Still, it would be useful to see the code you are using for `hook_form_alter()` (as you wrote, "When I try to access this form using form alter […[…]").

Comment: @kiamlaluno I have added the code snippet to my question. Kindly see that and tell me whether the code does work or not.

Comment: It would be perfect if you would show also the code for `main_menu_content_type_form_main_menu_node_form_alter_callback()`; if that function contains code that is wrong, users cannot report any changes you should do to your code to make it work.

Comment: Can you try using actual `hook_form_alter` instead of `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter` ? The latter hook has some issues with the order that it gets called in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would be able to give you some detailed information about what you are doing wrong with [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) if you included some actual code from your custom module. However, since you are not giving any specifics, you can watch the video: [How to build beautiful forms in Drupal 7](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=syqsH2CEu6U#t=28m10s) (note that I entered the URL so that it starts at the moment where the ajax is described). About 5 minutes of watching this will probably give you the answer to your question (since it describes exactly how to use ajax with hook_form_alter), but if you are really impatient, the actual code is shown somewhere around [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=syqsH2CEu6U#t=30m56s).

If you want to see a live, well-tested and documented example of a form being altered using ajax, there is one in the [Examples](http://drupal.org/project/examples) module. You can find the actual hook [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ajax_example%21ajax_example_node_form_alter.inc/function/ajax_example_form_node_form_alter/8) and the callback function [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ajax_example%21ajax_example_node_form_alter.inc/function/ajax_example_form_node_callback/8).

I hope this helps. If it doesn't, give us some more background about your code and we will be able to tell you exactly what you are doing wrong.

Comment: @F123K I wanted to alter the existing fields in the form rather than adding new field to the form. So please tell me how that could be done.

Comment: Post edited with a sample hook and the callback function.